# Aeroo reports: ошибка при использовании ir.actions.report.xml.report_type: 'aeroo'

Tags: python, python-2.x, odoo

Есть [odoo](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjACahUKEwiP3Ynks-THAhWCD3IKHSmVBj4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fodoo%2Fodoo&usg=AFQjCNEd33_QMTgqi4CdhboHVZzh3eUSBQ&sig2=jYX_z9Pdi__6ibDkIrRjcw) с самописным модулем табеля учёта рабочего времени. Обычно отчёты создавались через меню интерфейса, но куда как рациональнее по-моему описывать их через xml во views.

Соответственно, вот запись в xml-файле:

```
<record id="report_person_card_id" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
   <field name="name">doc print</field>
   <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
   <field name="report_name">person_card</field>
   <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
   <field name="type">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
   <field name="in_format">oo-odt</field>
   <field name="tml_source">file</field>
   <field name="report_rml">/tabel2.odt</field>
   <field name="parser_state">default</field>
</record>
```

К сожалению, она выдаёт ошибку:

```
ParseError: "Wrong value for ir.actions.report.xml.report_type: 'aeroo'" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/Tabel/views/tabel.xml:5, near
<record id="report_person_card_id" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
   <field name="name">doc_print</field>
   <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
   <field name="report_name">person_card</field>
   <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
   <field name="type">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
   <field name="in_format">oo-odt</field>
   <field name="tml_source">file</field>
   <field name="report_rml">/tabel2.odt</field>
   <field name="parser_state">default</field>
</record>
```

Пробовал менять этот самый тип отчёта на стандартные: от дефолтного pdf до odt, но безрезультатно. Копаю в направлении addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py, поскольку это может быть связано с поведением самого aeroo reports, но наверняка сказать не могу.

В общем, буду признателен за любой годный совет. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как посоветовали на английском СО, добавил в **openerp.py** моего модуля зависимость:

```
`'depends': ["base", "report_aeroo"],`
```

По всей видимости, не хватало именно этого.

Comment: Интересно.
А почему тогда работало, если создавал через меню интерфейса?
Ведь, как я понимаю, зависимости тоже не было.